# Is there any setting in Emacs to choose perlbrew over perl?

Tags: debugging, perl

I have a `Perl` project (developed in Ubuntu 14.04) which cannot be built on `perl 5.18.2`, but it works on `Perlbrew 5.22.0`. I have tried to use `M-x perldb` in `Emacs` but it looks like `Emacs` calls `Perl 5.18.2` by default. Is there a way to choose `Perlbrew` in `Emacs` for debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the command run by perldb by changing `gud-perldb-command-name`.  Its default value is set to `"perl -d"`.

Answer (score 1):

These elisps may help you:

- https://github.com/kentaro/perlbrew.el
- https://github.com/dams/perlbrew-mini.el

They seems to be pretty old, so please check them (I myself don't use perlbrew).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is probably to ensure the correct Perlbrew perl binary is used in the same way as usual for Perlbrew, and *then* launch Emacs in that environment.

Normally that would be something like

```
perlbrew switch X
perlbrew use X
```

See also: https://perlbrew.pl/